# Android studio build instant app release variant

Tags: android

I am playing with the [topkea instant app codelab](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-topeka/tree/multiModule) and when I am trying to run the release build variant of the instant app module I get the error dialog

[image]

Is it possible to test the release variant of the instant app locally or do you have to build the apk, upload it to the play console and run the alpha tests there?

Comment: Clear Project -> Sync Gradle and then try again.

Comment: Tried that, also in Edit Configurations I cleared the instant app cache but am getting the same error dialog.